# How do I check is full binary tree?

Tags: prolog, binary-tree

How do I check full binary tree in prolog? I have the 2 base cases

1) if is empty tree, return yes

2) if is just root only, return yes

I'm stuck at the third one and I not sure what should I do with it. We only allow to use 1 arity: full(T).

```
btree([]).
btree([H|T]):-btree(T).
btree([H|T]):-btree(H),btree(T).

full([]).
full([H]).
full([H|T]):-
```

anyone can guide me please. My idea is a tree does not have two nonempty tree then it is a full binary tree.

P/S: I am still new to stackoverflow. If I did ask something silly or improper way please do tell me. I want to learn how to use stackoverflow and also make sure of it in proper way.

Comment: Make a predicate `helper(T,H)` that tests whether `T` is a full tree of height `H`. Then define `full(T) :- helper(T,H).`

Comment: Sorry can I get some examples from you please? Not the answer but just some example that can give me some ideas what to do. Can?

Comment: how can I do it? What am I thinking now is if one of the tree missing 1 child then it is not full, but, I not sure how should I do that due to lack of examples or knowledge about prolog. @pyon

P/S: Sorry I guess I had accidentally remove your comment...

Comment: No, I removed my own comment myself. The new way I had found turned out not to be easier.

Comment: @pyon Oh okay. So do you have any examples can show me please? I got the ideas of what to do but I not sure how should I turn my idea into prolog.

Comment: What specific representation of binary trees are you using?

Comment: I can't tell what a tree looks like based upon your question. I just see simple lists. Have you decided what a valid tree looks like (the data representation)? You can't write your predicate without having that.

Comment: a valid tree is like btree([5, [6,[],[]], [2,[],[]]]). So if I do full([5, [3, [],[]], []]). it will return no.

Comment: @pyon your answer provided a good logical basis for the solution based upon the representation the OP provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you represent trees as follows:

- A leaf is an empty list.
- A non-leaf node is a three-element list, whose last two elements are the subtrees.

Then:

```
helper([], 0).
helper([_,L,R], H) :- H #= G + 1, helper(L, G), helper(R, G).
/* Old version: helper([_,L,R], H) :- helper(L, G), helper(R, G), H is G + 1.
 * The improvement in the new version was suggested by lurker. Thanks!
 */

full(T) :- helper(T, _).
```

This works because full binary trees can be inductively defined as follows:

- A leaf node is a full binary tree of height 0.
- An non-leaf node whose children are both full binary trees of height `G`, is itself a full binary tree of height `G + 1`.

Comment: Although this basically works, a couple of comments. You should use more descriptive predicate and variable names. `G` and `H` represent "depth" which doesn't contain the letter "g". Something like `Depth` and `SubDepth` would be better. `full_tree` rather than `full` would be less generic. And `helper` can also be called `full_tree` since the arity is different and Prolog can distinguish (`full_tree/1` versus `full_tree/2`). Also, this doesn't work in the general case, as `full(T)` query will stack overflow. Use `Depth #= SubDepth + 1` *before* recursive `helper/2` calls.

Comment: @lurker: I chose `H` for “height”, and `G` because it is `H`'s predecessor in the alphabet. As for the name `full`, it seemed to be a part of the problem specification, so I didn't change it myself. I agree that `full_tree` would have been better.

Comment: In that case, `H0`, `H1` etc is easier to grasp.

Comment: @lurker: Why don't you write your own answer? `Depth #>= 0` will be needed, though.

Comment: `H #>= 1` is missing! This will improve termination properties.

Comment: @false Woops! At this point, we should just tell OP to accept lurker's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would first probably choose a different representation for binary tree. In Prolog, it's generally more conventional and efficient to use a simple atom (such as `nil`) as a nil node, and something like `btree(Value, Left, Right)` as the tree term. Outside of that, the solution looks quite like what @pyon suggested.

```
% full_btree succeeds if `Tree` is a full binary tree

full_btree(Tree) :-
    full_btree(Tree, _).

full_btree(nil, 0).
full_btree(b(_, LeftTree, RightTree), Depth) :-
    Depth #> 0,
    SubDepth #= Depth - 1,
    full_btree(LeftTree, SubDepth),
    full_btree(RightTree, SubDepth).
```

The condition `Depth #> 0` ensures, regardless of inputs, that the depth will not become negative, and thus helps ensure termination.

Comment: `s(X)` for a different representation **alone**.

Comment: But ... it's not so much about efficiency, rather convention: A list should rather contain similar elements, and rather be possibly empty or of a different length than 3.

Comment: @false agreed, but I had also heard it is more efficient than lists, or no?

Comment: This representation is more memory efficient without any obvious downsides. Compare `b(x, nil,  nil)` to `.(x, .([], .([], [])))`.

Comment: @Boris: True! Yet, the `s(X)` is what has been known as `+1`.

Comment: Boris: "not as relational" - I do not see a difference in this example. And most probably `s(X)` is much more space efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, since there is already an answer that doesn't answer the question at face value, here is mine. It doesn't add much anything to [the answer by @lurker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42880246/1812457), it just offers details and explanations that were too much for comments. It also avoids CLP(FD) completely, which is why I felt it should be a separate answer.

You can start (as @lurker has) by using a more conventional binary tree representation. The empty tree is `nil`, and the non-empty tree is `bt(Value, Left, Right)` where `Value` is the value at this node and `Left` and `Right` are the left and right sub-trees. This is the conventional representation because it is at the very least more memory efficient. A "leaf" (a tree without sub-trees) is, in your original representation:

```
.(Value, .([], .([], [])))
```

instead of:

```
bt(Value, nil, nil)
```

The amount of memory needed to represent the two would be different between different Prolog implementations, but I don't know how to make the first *smaller* than the second.

Then: as [@false commented above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866976/how-do-i-check-is-full-binary-tree#comment72865845_42880246), a list is usually a collection of Things which conventionally has the following properties:

- There can be no Things, or any number of Things in the collection;
- The order of Things matters;
- All the Things are somehow the same.

Using a list like you do breaks the last convention: the first argument is a value, while the second and third arguments are trees.

This doesn't exclude using list for representing a binary tree but it is unfamiliar.

With this out of the way: successor arithmetic is a silly way of doing actual arithmetic, but it is very convenient if you want to use pattern matching for non-negative integers. You cannot do it with the built-in integer type of Prolog, like `0` or `-23` or whatever. Successor arithmetic gives you:

- a zero which is structurally different from all positive integers: `0` vs `s(_)`
- adding and subtracting is done by pattern matching, and both are done with the same operation: `X + 1` is `s(X)`.
- negative numbers are not possible

So, you could define your "full tree" like this:

```
full_btree(T) :-
    full_btree(T, _).

full_btree(nil, 0).
full_btree(bt(_, L, R), s(D)) :-
    full_btree(L, D),
    full_btree(R, D).
```

The `s(D)` and the two `D`s state that the tree in your first argument is one deeper than the sub-trees, and that both sub-trees are the same depth. The empty tree `nil` has a depth of 0 (as defined in the first clause of `full_btree/2`).

This works as follows:

```
?- full_btree(nil).
true.

?- full_btree(bt(x, nil, nil)).
true.

?- full_btree(bt(x, bt(y, nil, nil), nil)).
false.

?- full_btree(bt(x, bt(y, nil, nil), bt(z, nil, nil))).
true.

?- full_btree(T), numbervars(T).
T = nil ;
T = bt(A, nil, nil) ;
T = bt(A, bt(B, nil, nil), bt(C, nil, nil)) ;
T = bt(A, bt(B, bt(C, nil, nil), bt(D, nil, nil)), bt(E, bt(F, nil, nil), bt(G, nil, nil))) . % and so on
```

One more thing: to close the circle, you can do successor arithmetic with lists, too. Just use `[]` instead of 0 and `[_|X]` for `s(X)`. With this, you would have:

```
full_tree(nil, []).
full_tree(bt(_, L, R), [_|D]) :-
    full_tree(L, D),
    full_tree(R, D).
```

This is slightly less memory efficient, instead of `s(s(s(0)))` you would have `.(_, .(_, ,(_, [])))`. However! it is now much easier to make actual integers out of the successor-notation integers, and the other way round: just use `length/2`. Writing a predicate that converts between `s(s(...))` and an integer *that works both ways* in pure Prolog is not as trivial. I think it is possible to search Stackoverflow for such questions.

Comment: `s(X)` for using `s(X)`. This will remain the fastest version for long. Yes, successor-arithmetics for performance reasons!